# What can I do about a bad traceroute?

Tags: internet

I live in Australia I have high latency (~450 ms) to Digitalocean Amsterdam because the traceroute takes a strange route

Usually to Europe I get ~350 ms latency

Tracert between me and Digitalocean Amsterdam

```
 1     3 ms     4 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
 2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 3    14 ms    81 ms     9 ms  58.160.28.xx
 4    16 ms    11 ms    11 ms  te6-3.agg2.pie.bigpond.net.au [58.160.31.250]
 5    10 ms    10 ms     9 ms  bundle-ether4.wel-edge902.perth.telstra.net [203.50.112.56]
 6    12 ms    22 ms    11 ms  bundle-ether7.wel-core3.perth.telstra.net [203.50.6.190]
 7    54 ms    44 ms    42 ms  bundle-ether7.fli-core1.adelaide.telstra.net [203.50.11.18]
 8    49 ms    47 ms    49 ms  bundle-ether9.win-core10.melbourne.telstra.net [203.50.11.91]
 9    59 ms    59 ms    61 ms  bundle-ether12.ken-core10.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.11.122]
10    59 ms    62 ms    59 ms  bundle-ether1.pad-gw11.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.6.61]
11    61 ms    58 ms    62 ms  bundle-ether1.sydp-core04.sydney.reach.com [203.50.13.90]
12   174 ms   193 ms   177 ms  i-0-5-0-2.siko-core03.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.141.234]
13   173 ms   172 ms   174 ms  180.87.180.6
14   162 ms   148 ms   156 ms  ix-xe-8-2-2-0.tcore1.TV2-Tokyo.as6453.net [180.87.180.5]
15   174 ms   158 ms   160 ms  if-et-21-2.hcore1.KV8-Chiba.as6453.net [120.29.217.67]
16   437 ms   450 ms   437 ms  if-ae-24-2.tcore2.PDI-Palo-Alto.as6453.net [66.198.144.56]
17   440 ms   444 ms   438 ms  if-ae-5-2.tcore2.SQN-San-Jose.as6453.net [64.86.21.1]
18   440 ms   480 ms   442 ms  if-ae-1-2.tcore1.SQN-San-Jose.as6453.net [63.243.205.1]
19   441 ms   440 ms   442 ms  if-ae-12-2.tcore1.NTO-New-York.as6453.net [63.243.128.28]
20   439 ms   437 ms   439 ms  if-ae-7-2.tcore1.N0V-New-York.as6453.net [63.243.128.26]
21   438 ms   446 ms   440 ms  if-ae-2-2.tcore2.N0V-New-York.as6453.net [216.6.90.22]
22   449 ms   444 ms   443 ms  if-ae-4-2.tcore2.L78-London.as6453.net [80.231.131.157]
23   520 ms   440 ms   441 ms  if-ae-8-2.tcore2.AV2-Amsterdam.as6453.net [80.231.131.6]
24   451 ms   443 ms   441 ms  80.231.152.134
25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
26   463 ms   440 ms   437 ms  95.85.38.xxx
```

and between me and OVH France (I don't think it quite reaches the server but it gets to france with 343ms)

```
 1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
 2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 3    10 ms     9 ms    10 ms  58.160.28.xxx
 4    11 ms    18 ms    12 ms  te6-3.agg2.pie.bigpond.net.au [58.160.31.250]
 5    16 ms    10 ms    11 ms  bundle-ether4.wel-edge902.perth.telstra.net [203.50.112.56]
 6    19 ms    11 ms    11 ms  bundle-ether7.wel-core3.perth.telstra.net [203.50.6.190]
 7    41 ms    47 ms    42 ms  bundle-ether7.fli-core1.adelaide.telstra.net [203.50.11.18]
 8    49 ms    49 ms    48 ms  bundle-ether9.win-core10.melbourne.telstra.net [203.50.11.91]
 9    58 ms    82 ms    63 ms  bundle-ether12.ken-core10.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.11.122]
10    58 ms    61 ms    60 ms  bundle-ether1.pad-gw11.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.6.61]
11    62 ms    61 ms    59 ms  bundle-ether1.sydp-core04.sydney.reach.com [203.50.13.90]
12   209 ms   207 ms   207 ms  i-12.paix-core01.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.136.194]
13   204 ms   250 ms   206 ms  i-0-5-0-5.paix02.bi.telstraglobal.net [202.40.149.126]
14   203 ms   204 ms   203 ms  po3.pal-5-6k.ca.us [178.32.135.150]
15   251 ms   252 ms   255 ms  be100-1235.chi-1-a9.il.us [198.27.73.188]
16   273 ms   269 ms   268 ms  be10-1312.bhs-g1-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.196]
17   277 ms   292 ms   284 ms  be100-1037.nwk-1-a9.nj.us [192.99.146.98]
18   339 ms   339 ms   351 ms  be100-1295.ldn-1-a9.uk.eu [192.99.146.126]
19   347 ms   344 ms   370 ms  be11-1187.rbx-g1-a9.fr.eu [91.121.128.86]
20   343 ms   341 ms   343 ms  vl21.rbx-g1-a75.fr.eu [213.251.128.77]
21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted the traceroute. You can remove the first few and last few local hops.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can change Internet service providers.
2. You can email the traceroute to your ISP and to Digital Ocean and ask them if there's anything they can do. (There probably isn't, but it can't hurt to try.)
3. You can use a VPN hosted somewhere between you and Digital Ocean and hope that the route through the VPN is better.
4. You can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Traceroute is a useful tool for your own network where you know what to expect. Traceroute on the Internet is a fool's game. Many ISPs will reroute traceroute and ICMP in an effort to keep you from discovering their internal network design. Because of that, the traceroute results that you see may bear no relationship to the path your regular data traffic travels over the Internet. Your traceroute and ICMP traffic may be using backup links to backup ISPs connected to your ISP.

Even if your ISP doesn't do this, other ISPs through which your traffic must pass to get to the destination may be doing this, and if your traffic passes through multiple ISPs doing this, you have absolutely no idea how your traffic is actually travelling.